# Can you do a paired t test in SPSS or GraphPad with only means, errors and N?

Tags: spss, t-test, p-value, paired-comparisons

I have to verify some results. I have only the mean and its st. error, not the raw data. In a research paper they did a paired t test. Is it possible to check whether their p value is right by only using the means, st. errors and N, in SPSS or GraphPad?

Comment: Computation of test out of statistics, not the data, is usually called "test calculator". Unfortunately and strangely, SPSS lacks such a module. Of course, if you are an experienced user to work with command syntax, it is easy to program it in SPSS. But there are many online test calculators, incliding [this](http://www.openepi.com/OE2.3/Menu/OpenEpiMenu.htm), [this](http://graphpad.com/quickcalcs/ttest1.cfm), [this](http://studentsttest.com/).

Comment: If you have the mean *of the differences*, and its standard error, yes. If you only have the means of the first and the second groups and their separate standard errors, then no.

Comment: That is what I have. The means of the first and second groups and their separate SEM

Comment: I want to be sure I am getting this clear.. For example: Before a particular treatment the variable waist (cm) has a mean of 87, error 8.7 and N is 24. After treatment it is 86.3, 8.7 and 24 respectively. The research showed significance of <0.001... I didnt feel much of a diff from 87 to 86.3, and however on using the means I was getting a p value of 0.954. So Nick are u suggesting that irrespective of means, there are high chances that the raw data will show significance, and that we cannot simply estimate sig using means alone in a paired t test?

Comment: Without information about how dependent the measurements on the pairs are, or information on the pair-differences, you have no way to tell how significant it might be. It's quite possible that looking at the data unpaired (the information you have) could look far from significant, while the actual full information is highly significant ... indeed, that's the point of pairing in the first place.

Comment: fida - I've just made a data set which has a paired t-test p-value of <0.0005 but where the two sample means are 87.04 vs 86.26 and the sample sds are 7.43 vs 7.47; quite similar to your case. It's certainly possible ... but it's equally possible to get a very high p-value with another sample with exactly the same means and sds as I gave.

Comment: @ttnphns - you can do this in syntax with the MANOVA command.

Comment: @Jeremy I could do it via 3 or 4 other 'black box' procedures as well :-). In my answer, I aimed to show the computations. I can show them outside matrix session too.

Answer (score 2):

The first step in computing the paired t test is to compute the difference between each set of matched pairs (after - before in many cases). All the rest of the calculations are based on that list of differences. If you know the mean of the differences, as well as the SD (or SEM) and sample size, you can compute the paired t test. The t ratio equals the mean of the differences divided by the SEM of those differences. The df equals number of pairs minus 1.

If you only know the mean and SD (or SEM) of the "before" data and separately the "after" data, then you cannot compute the paired t test. The information simply isn'there.

Answer (score 1):

In your situation - when you don't know anything about the within-pairs *differences* but know only statistics of the two matched samples separately - you need to know also the *covariance* or correlation between the two samples in order to be able to perform paired t-test.

Let's program paired t-test 'calculator' in SPSS matrix session, assuming that you know the covariance.

```
matrix.
*Enter the statistics: means, their errors, the covariance, and N.
compute MEAN1 = 1.6720.
compute SEM1 = .15315.
compute MEAN2 = 1.8674.
compute SEM2 = .14161.
compute COV = -.69211.
compute N = 50.

*Restore st. deviations out of st. errors.
compute S1 = SEM1*sqrt(N).
compute S2 = SEM2*sqrt(N).

*Paired t-test.
compute TVAL = (MEAN1-MEAN2)/sqrt((S1**2+S2**2-2*COV)/N).
compute PVAL = 2*(1-tcdf(abs(TVAL),N-1)).
print {MEAN1-MEAN2,TVAL,N-1,PVAL} /title 'Paired t-test result'
                  /clabels 'mean dif' 'stud t' 'df' 'p 2sided' /format f12.4.
end matrix.

***********
Paired t-test result
 mean dif       stud t           df     p 2sided
   -.1954       -.7323      49.0000        .4675
```

Answer (score 0):

You are out of luck for the paired t test, since you don't have the necessary data, but for simple t tests based only on the summary statistics, the SPSSINC SUMMARY TTEST extension command allows you to do this from a dialog box.  You can get that command from the SPSS Community website at www.ibm.com/developerworks/spssdevcentral.  It requires the Python Essentials also available via that site, depending on your Statistics version.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the suggestions. Helped me big time!!!